# Index out of range exception in Merge Sort Text file reader

Tags: c#, sorting, mergesort, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm trying to sort a text file using a merge sort. I keep getting an index out of range exception when I try to run it though. I'll Specify the areas where the exception occurs.

```
class Program
{
    static public void DoMerge(int[] numbers, int left, int mid, int right)
    {

        int[] temp = new int[25];

        int i, left_end, num_elements, tmp_pos;



        left_end = (mid - 1);

        tmp_pos = left;

        num_elements = (right - left + 1);



        while ((left <= left_end) && (mid <= right))
        {

            if (numbers[left] <= numbers[mid])

                temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[left++];

            else

                temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[mid++];

        }



        while (left <= left_end)

            temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[left++];

        while (mid <= right)
```

The above part is fine but below I get one exception.

```
            temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[mid++];
```

The next few lines are fine.

```
        for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++)
        {

            numbers[right] = temp[right];

            right--;

        }

    }



    static public void MergeSort_Recursive(int[] numbers, int left, int right)
    {

        int mid;



        if (right > left)
        {

            mid = (right + left) / 2;
```

The next few lines all give me exceptions as well.

```
            MergeSort_Recursive(numbers, left, mid);

            MergeSort_Recursive(numbers, (mid + 1), right);

            DoMerge(numbers, left, (mid + 1), right);
```

As far as I've seen the rest is fine, but I'll add it just so you guys can see.

```
        }

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fileNumbers = File.ReadAllText("sort(5).txt");
        string[] intNumbers = fileNumbers.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        int[] numbers = new int[intNumbers.Length];
        int len = 999;
        //for (int n = 0; n < intNumbers.Length; n++)
        //{
        //    numbers[n] = int.Parse(intNumbers[n]);
        //}

        Console.WriteLine("MergeSort: ");
        MergeSort_Recursive(numbers, 0, len - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

The text file I'm trying to read has 500 numbers, highest number being 999, the smallest is 6, the numbers are pretty random and I have to sort them.
P.S. I know what an Out of Range Exception is and I know what causes it, hence the reason why I'm asking why my code is throwing the exception.

Comment: @Dour High Arch No, I know what an Index out of range exception is. So that is not a duplicate, I did get it solved with the help of another person posting an answer below, but please try not to jump to a conclusion when you don't read a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sorting code looks to be mostly fine.  I ran it on a small array and it sorted correctly.

There are two problems in your code that are causing your out of range exceptions.

The first problem is that you are setting `len` to 999.

You mentioned that the file contains 500 numbers, but it would be best to just set `len` to `numbers.Length`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string fileNumbers = File.ReadAllText("sort(5).txt");
    string[] intNumbers = fileNumbers.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    int[] numbers = new int[intNumbers.Length];
    int len = numbers.Length;
    for (int n = 0; n < intNumbers.Length; n++)
    {
        numbers[n] = int.Parse(intNumbers[n]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("MergeSort: ");
    MergeSort_Recursive(numbers, 0, len - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);

    //Console.Read(); //Not sure what this is for....
}
```

The second problem is when you create your `temp` array, you are creating it with a length of 25.
This will fix that part:

```
int[] temp = new int[numbers.Length];
```

Note that a better approach would be to create your `temp` array in your main function, and pass it as a parameter to `MergeSort_Recursive()` and `DoMerge()`, so that you don't have to create a new array on each merge operation.

Comment: I'm not sure if something wrong at this point or if the list is just too long but it starts around 244 and then goes to then end, I know there are more numbers than that, other that that everything works, thank you for being so helpful.

Comment: No problem.  I would say try it first with a hard-coded array, get that working, and then get it working with the contents of the file.   It's possible that for some reason the entire contents of the file are not getting read successfully.  Also, write `numbers.Length` to the console to see if the amount of numbers read from the file are what you expect.

Comment: I managed to get it fixed by adding (... + "\t") so it split it into 4 columns. The command prompt I guess isn't big enough for all of the numbers. Thanks again for your help.